# calculate matrix

Tags: java

I have a task that ask to program the [game of life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).

I have difficulties calculating the next generation.
The problem is:
suppose i have this matrix M4x4 here:
(dots = dead; + = alive)

. + . .
. + . +
+ . . .
. . + .

The neighbors of the M are equal matrices.
So the neighbors of M(0,0) are (0,1) (1,1) (1,0) (1,3) (0,3) (3,3) (3,0) and (3,1).
How can i write that?
Should i create a 6x6 Matrix where i put those values? Or java has some methods that allows a more elegant solution to the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create normalize method

```
int normalize(int i, int max){
    if(i==-1) return max;
    if(i==max+1) return 0;
    return i;
}
```

and neighbors will be

```
int x, y; current
for(int i = -1; i<=1; i++) {
    for(int i = -1; i<=1; i++) {
        if(i==0 && j==0) continue;
        print(normalize(x+i, maxX), normalize(y+j, maxY);
    }
}
```